# How to print out the common name of all certificates in current folder?

Tags: bash, shell, openssl

I would like to filter out all common names of certificates in the current folder to troubleshoot which certificates are trusted.

Comment: For HTTPS, RFC2818 has deprecated CNs in preference of the SubjectAlternativeName (SAN) field instead (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Common name can be filtered](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/openssl-get-common-name-cn-from-ssl-certificate-on-linux-unix/) using the following command:

```
$ openssl x509 -noout -subject -in /etc/ssl/glusterfs.pem
```

[Looping over files](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-loop-over-file/) in the current folder can be achieved with:

```
$ for f in *; do echo "Processing $f file..."; done
```

To display common names for all certificates in current folder:

```
$ for f in *; do openssl x509 -noout -subject -in $f; done
```